# Constructin an circuit from bacic logic gates

Tags: logic, circuit

I have n inputs and n corresponding outputs, the state of output N° i depends on the state of the input N° 1 to n, EXCEPT N° i.

To be more precise, if any of the input 1 to n except i is true, then the corresponding output is true; If all of the input 1 to n except i is false, then the corresponding output is false.

Is it possible to construct such circuit via basic logic gates when n becomes infinite?

Answer (score 0):

yes and there is an example where n = 3 :

[image]

Comment: Yes but when n becomes infinite is there a feasible solution?

Comment: the variable n, will never be infinite in real world problem, but lets suppose n is inifinite then i suppose that every **or** logic gate has infinitly many input gate, and that solve the problem